# .htaccess help, removing page1.html (pagination)

Tags: .htaccess, pagination

I am trying to remove abc.com/page1.html from the website as abc.com corresponds to same content as of abc.com/page1.html.

I have tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/page1.html /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't seems to work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteRule already works on a URL-path of URL. Your full URL is abc.com/page1.html, but your URL-path is /page1.html. Leading slash is also excluded so in fact only 'page1.html' is matched against rules.

I believe this code will do a trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)page1.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for your reply, However abc.com/page1.html is part of one category.
i.e., abc.com/cat1/page1.html is another category.

Comment: I see, I updated my answer to match start and end of the string

Comment: It works only for parent url. i.e abc.com/page1.html and not for abc.com/newproduct/page1/html

Comment: OK, you should explain a question in a more details next time, I updated regexp to handle both situations: abc.com/page1.html leads to abc.com, abc.com/newproduct/page1.html leads to abc.com/newproducts

Comment: It works. !! i am not sure why mine one failed, if you can just guide me on that as well it would be great. 

Thank you for you help. Appreciated

Comment: The cause of error is leading slash in your rule before page1.html. As I said, leading slash is truncated inside .htaccess. It worked fine to address redirects from /myproduct/page1.html to /myproducts but failed to handle redirect for the main page because you URL-path is page1.html in this case. Quick googling gave me this article: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708. Hope it helps to understand the whole process.